# Questions about springboot

Tags: java

How do you add a class to the "nsh_common" project?

So that the "nsh_user" project can immediately use the class just added to the "nsh_common" project?

[image: screen shot]

Comment: I pulled in your image, but I think your question is still unclear. You should really invest some more time to explain what exactly you are doing. What IDE are you using? Where is the *project definition* coming from, and so on.

Comment: Sorry, but i couldn't get what you mean. do you want to know how child parent projects could interact or what ?

Comment: Sorry, I may not be able to describe it clearly. Let me see how it should be described.

Comment: I use eclipse development tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I see you are using eclipse or STS for your project development. If you just right click on `nsh_user` and go to `build path` after that choose `Configure Build path` after go the `Projects` tab and Add your `nsh_common`. That will solve your problem.

Comment: I'm sorry, it can solve this problem,but I need to package the "nsh_common" project first, but I want the "nsh_common" project to add classes without packaging, and the "nsh_user" project can be used in real time

Comment: Sorry, Jayesh Choudhary, your method worked. I didn't see clearly. . I'm really sorry.